# redirect web server with no-ip and port forwarding in livebox

Tags: linux, networking, webserver, port-forwarding, dynamic-dns

I want my  Apache web server running on a Livebox (home router appliance running Linux) to be accessible from the Internet (WAN).

I installed and configured the application noip2 on my Ubuntu PC. When I ping my hostname, it redirects me to my WAN ip, which is what I wanted. But I cannot access my Apache web server.

I tried this:

- Disabling the `iptables` firewall configuration or the firewall of my Sagem modem.
- Port forwarding on sagem modem (NAT).
- Configuration of Apache.

What else can I try? How can I make my web server accessible from the WAN side?

Comment: Certain ISPs like Verizon block inbound port 80 connections on residential accounts. Try configuring the web server to use a different port and see if that works

Comment: I guess you mean a LiveBox from Orange Tel? There different models. Search for "port forwarding" + <model> + LiveBox on google.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the modems can put a local IP into its DMZ, allowing external access to local servers. Check your modem for this option.

Comment: yes my modem contain this option, it's activated but not worked, now i try to disble firewall in the modem, same thing. >in my server host i test port with nmap : nmap @IP_WAN => the http port is open and i test with netstat as the port is open???!!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are referring to the [livebox server](https://livebox.co.in).
Within Livebox, you can go to the IP settings page and set the port forwarding for port number 80 to access your web server. And,Why do you need a webserver in the first place since Livebox has a built-in webserver?